# Valid Cell reference stops functioning

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro running which suddenly throws error '1004' mid run after a line using a range reference, even though this reference works perfectly up to that point. Please see code snippet example below.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws1 as Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")
Dim PasteRange as Range
Set PasteRange = ws1.Range("AJ4:AM4") 'This is actually a variable range, but this is not important for this question
Dim CheckCell as Range
Dim ColCntr as Long
Dim ReviewCntr as Long
Dim LoopCntr as Long
ReviewCntr = ws1.Range("AA1").Value 'This cell only contains numerical values

For Each CheckCell in PasteRange
    If LoopCntr = 0 Then
        'A lot of code happens here, referencing CheckCell, all working 
        'flawlessly. Untill...
        ColCntr = CheckCell.Column + ReviewCntr 'Final good working line
    ElseIf LoopCntr <> 0 Then
        CheckCell.Offset(0, BackSet2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 '<-- error occurs
        'Some More Code
    End If
    LoopCntr = LoopCntr + 1
Next CheckCell
```

Suddenly an object defined error occurs on the line

```
CheckCell.Offset(0, BackSet2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

and I have no idea why or how this error suddenly occurs, especially because the line above it, the reference is still valid. Compiling the project via the Debug DropDown menu yields no errors. When hovering the mouse over `Checkcell` when stepping through the code it is valid and gives values and what not in a pop up window.

The moment the code hits that specific line, the pop up reads:

> Application-defined or Object-defined error.

Hovering over `BackSet2` in that line reads a numerical value, meaning that the offset is working correctly. Hovering over `CheckCell` references located prior to this line still yield relevant information in the pop up window.

Can anyone tell me what the error is here?

Comment: What is `BackSet2` number on that line when it is errored? (Also you don't need to test for `ElseIf LoopCntr <> 0` because you already tested `If LoopCntr = 0`

Comment: @jamheadart I think you just cracked it for me. BackSet2 = -106, so it references outside of the workbook range.  Gonna try and fix that. thanks for the quick and good remark. (And also for the ElseIf LoopCntr <>0 tip)

Comment: No probs - Can just use `Else` instead of `ElseIf` - it'll be tiny amounts quicker since it's not actually testing any condition, and  is maybe better practice.